# May a simple user impede someone to discuss about a question he closed on a chatroom?

Tags: discussion, moderation, rude-or-abusive

Reading [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720866/failed-to-decode-json-object-when-calling-a-get-request-in-flask-python), which may be good or bad, I wanted to discss it with the user who closed it. And after explaining my point of view I got kicked out of the forum within a few comments with this message:

> I really don't want to discuss this with some random user as soon as I get into the room in the morning. You've misread the question.

[Full conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42828186#42828186).

I do not know if it's tolerated in Stack Overflow but I find it very awkward, against the new [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct), as well as putting down someone asking for discussing a question closure where he was trying to help.

Comment: That question was not closed by a moderator, it was closed by a regular user.  Said user is not obligated to discuss a question with you in chat if they don't want to.

Comment: @Servy, ho, sorry, I thought it was a moderator priviledge as moving messages from a chat room

Comment: Sigh, expert gold badgers get harassed about their decisions everywhere.  Clearly you didn't make it convincing enough to change his mind, get ahead by editing the question.

Comment: @Servy I updated the title then

Comment: @HansPassant Maybe not granting them such rights if they don't have the interpersonal skills to handle these kinds of conversation ?

Comment: @Marine1 You're the only one who's acted inappropriately here.  There's nothing at all wrong with someone saying they aren't interested in discussing the question with you in a chatroom.

Comment: @Servy but if he closed it, there is nothing able to discuss with him the question at all? So I acted inappropriately? I mean it's offensive to be called "random user" and prohibit to discuss when discussing of a question

Comment: @Marine1 I don't know the rules of that room but if I disagree with a closure I leave a comment under the question itself. Is there a specific reason you pinged them on chat, instead of the main site?

Comment: @Marine1 You can ask to discuss it with him, sure.  But you can't *force* him to discuss it with you if he doesn't want to, or call him rude for politely telling you that he disagrees with you and doesn't wish to discuss it further.

Comment: @user2285236, yes, his profile said him open to discussion in this forum. So that's why I called him before being called "random user" and kicked out because he didn't wanted to discuss it when it's the morning in his country. _That's_ quite rude and not very polite.

Comment: @Marine1 Either that user has changed their profile or you have misread it. It currently only states: _"Come join us in the sopython chatroom!"_

Comment: @AndréKool, I don't feel the contradiction

Comment: @Marine1 It's not contradiction, you just invented meaning that's not there. They totally don't say "come discuss question closure with me". That's just not there.

Comment: '*I mean it's offensive to be called "random user"*' - No it isn't, to them, you are a random user in the same way to you they are a random user, they don't know you so what else do you want them to say?

Comment: I'm not sure what's offensive about being called a "random user". I am just a random user on Stack Overflow. User 215552 to be precise. I use my real name as my alias, but that's just my preference right now. I don't think it makes me any less "random" to the majority of other users on SO.

Comment: Calling a single user out on Meta for a closure that you disagree with doesn't strike me as a productive way to solve things. There are ways to get questions reopened, and trickier cases (and by cases I mean actual _content_ rather than users) can be brought here for a more accurate appreciation/scrutiny. Can we not make this a false argument towards SO being unwelcome?

Comment: So.... If someone is knowledgeable enough in a topic (gold tag badge-holder) but doesn't feel like discussing every single closure they do (and some of them do... **A lot**), we should make the site worse by revoking these privileges? I... Don't see it. What is insulting in what he said? He is a free user volunteering his time.... If he doesn't want to discuss, he doesn't have to. You can edit, send the question to the reopen queue. He doesn't have to be involved in the reopening. You think it would be ok for you to refuse him not wanting to discuss this further? Is **that** not rude?

Comment: @Patrice No, to the extent that I take as a principle an answer of the acts when one holds a power. With power comes responsabilites ... before the community which grants him and from which I am a stakeholder. If I make too much impression and he does not prefer to speak to me, it is only one more stone to the reputation that this site gives itself.

Comment: @Marine1 you have ways to get it reopened that don't involve talking to him. He is accountable to his actions, yes. If too much of his stuff gets reopened/flagged, something may come out of it. Does being accountable means he has the obligation to discuss in details EVERY moderation act he ever took? This is maybe where our opinions differ

Comment: @Patrice, no I agree, he doesn't have the obligation to discuss in details every moderation act he ever took, only those where one may ask to discuss about. In my country, refusing to talk to someone is very rude. But as I said about **ES**.stackoverflow, that may be cultural. Some people think that makes quality the prerogative of Stackoverflow. I think that this policy is at the expense of a quality of living-together. To which I give more importance.

Comment: I will even add that, instead of being closed, a question of which he is considered an expert, he could have left others, like myself, to answer this question in order to be able to aspire to become one. I don't understand this policy old users have at the expense of the new ones. It's so specific to SO in English.

Comment: @Marine1 sorry... How is 'only those one may ask to discuss about' not everyone? Potentially, every single downvote, close vote,or whatnot is something a user somewhere could want to discuss... That is a slippery slope to 'every moderation act'. In my country, if someone shows up at my door to discuss a stop I didn't do with my car earlier that day, they will likely be turned around.... Does that make me rude? Maybe. I don't think so. If his buy in to reopen was necessary, I'd see it differently. It isn't needed, so I see no reason to oblige him to discuss.

Comment: @Marine1 if the question is a dupe it SHOULD be closed as a dupe. There is no question about that. He isn't blocking others from answering. If he is right about the closure, he is simply making sure all answers are centralized. For the good of future visitors.

Comment: @Patrice You are free to respect the rules that your country imposes on you to live together. And I assume that preventing the question or discussion is not a source of learning. But it's irrelevant to the subject mentioned here.

Comment: @Marine1 this is no rules. Just common sense. I am happy to discuss in the appropriate time and place. Did you ping davidism on the question he closed? Leaving it to be his choice if he engages or not. Honestly having a blanket 'everyone should be willing to discuss everything with everyone else' is opened to so much abuse..... What of users who don't want to listen? Are we supposed to engage them *ad vitam eternam*? What if I discuss it with the OP. OP agreed with me but another user comes in and still wants to discuss? When do we stop this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172636/discussion-between-marine1-and-patrice).

Comment: Interesting how the next guy who came to post you sent to our chatroom yet haven't answered my comments there....for someone praising 'everyone should be willing to discuss all the time'.... Interesting action

Comment: @Patrice you missed my point, anyone granting with power must has to answer for his actions and not send stroll those who ask him for accounts. I do not know this user or the accounts you asked him. But please, let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172636/discussion-between-marine1-and-patrice)

Comment: I see no point. Other users have to be accountable to you for their moderation actions, but you don't seem to hold yourself accountable for what you say for the same amount of time. So meh, honestly, I see no great value in continuing. Andover chat.... We've tried that and you ended up ignoring my answers.

Comment: @Patrice I did read your questions and answered them! If you have one more, please ask me [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172636/discussion-between-marine1-and-patrice).

Comment: Lol.... Weird how the chat ends on MY comments though, but sure. Everyone has to discuss till the end of time. But you! Anyway. Have a good day, I am done

Comment: @Patrice, as I said, I'm happy to answer your questions [in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172636/discussion-between-marine1-and-patrice) if you do not have one, I can not do much for you. I can repeat still myself: anyone granted with power should not throw away those who ask questions about his decisions as to his use.

Comment: Have you... Read the chat? The last comments in there are mine. There are questions in there. I don't know what more you expect from me.... 'questions in the chat' are in there. You're not answering..... This is getting sillier and sillier. As I said, nothing really productive will come out anyway. Especially not if you ignore the questions already in the chat and ask me for more...

Comment: My dear @Patrice, this a Question & Answer website, what's you're question? Your last comment was a point you wanted to make. I'm happy you did!

Comment: Wow.... For someone praising interpersonal skills, that was pretty condescending. Not sure I appreciate. Honestly if you can't see in the chat 'this again begs the question', I am right. You aren't reading the chat. I've said it before. But I'm done. No need to answer. If my last comment didn't prompt you to re read my chat message to see the question in there, nothing will. Not continuing this pointless conversation will buy us both some free time. Adios

Comment: Your interpretation is free, @Patrice, but do not let it obscure your judgment, however, I asked you to continue this discussion in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172636/discussion-between-marine1-and-patrice).

Comment: @Marine1 To cut the discussion short: no, it is not appropriate to insist on a discussion with a user who doesn't want to discuss _in the context and the culture of Stack Overflow_.

Comment: @ModusTollens Well received, that why I'm plead for the specific case when a user his granted the power to close any posts, and if not to leave his power to others. And already not to throw away the questions of what the one we talk about called _random user_ who merely ask him for accounts on a question he was trying to answer. That sounds more fair, isn't it?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I promise you! And I am interested in engaging in authentic discussion! I even answered you when you asked me two months ago _any other community than Stack Overflow with [the] level of support  level of support [I'm expecting]_ from a site like SO. I answered **es**.SO which you misread as SO and left with _Lol, you cited Stack Overflow when I asked you of any other community than Stack Overflow. I think I'm done here_. that's even unfriendly in the term of CoC.

Comment: @Marine1 No, I did understand es.SO. I simply consider all SO sister sites to be one SO. I had asked you to cite me a site, *outside SO, outside all SO sites*, to which you had answered *another SO site*. I felt that very trollish. I see how it can have been misleading however. I sincerely believe that on no other online platform, that does not end with .stackoverflow.com, is there the possibility to express problems in a space where all community can interact.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier If you were part of it you would have felt the difference. They wouldn't have ever needed a CoC for instance. People are naturally friendly and welcoming there. I never had an argument with anyone. I would add that Programmez.com had quite a good level of support back in times if you really needed one outside of SE system.

Answer (score 24):

You may have a slight misunderstanding of the purpose and spirit of Stack Overflow.

This is not a social forum. We're not exactly here to discuss everything forever. Experts users are given extended privilege, because they have proven, time and again, that they *know* their subjects.

That user closed a question, chances are extremely high that they are right.

You don't seem to have shown a desire to actually consider that maybe they were right, and it's not like they hurt you or something by kicking you out of the chat (which they also happen to be room owner of).

As far as  public evidence is shown here, they were polite, and refused to get drawn in a conversation that had no tengent towards staying civil.

I support how they acted here.

Comment: In this case, I'm repending, I bow to the probability that he is extremely right to close the question he closed, and even consider that maybe this way of dealing with _random users_ is right as well. I will, however, suggest that cutting a conversation about discussing a question is yet another proof of the harshness of SO, but I am not an expert in interpersonal relationships

Comment: They have no obligation to continue a conversation they do not want to partake into. You chased them to a chat room. Maybe you want to revisit your definitions of rudeness?

Comment: @Marine I consider it rude when someone decides to pester me about something I don't want nor need to talk about, especially when  there is a procedure for achieving the result they want to achieve employing community consensus. I consider it rude when people twist things to make other people sound bad and themselves sound good, especially when it is so plain to see when looking at the evidence that the case is reversed. That makes me feel like you think I'm stupid, which would be fairly rude.

Comment: @TinyGiant So was I rude then ? I think that's twisting the truth. I act of my good right to discuss with him about his actions.

Comment: You have a right to discuss his actions with them as much as they have a right to not discuss their actions with you. Fairness for you, but not for them right? @Marine1

Comment: @Marine1 Do they not have the right to decline to speak with you?

Comment: @TinyGiant If users refuse to talk to each other, do you really have a community? Especially when some users have the rights that the community gives them for which any member of the community question his use, in this case, yes, it's unfair

Comment: You can't possibly mean that forcing people to have a conversation, rejecting the obvious global consensus, and name calling everyone else rude, is a better mark of a community member? If you can't make it so that other human beings have a *desire* to speak with you, the onus is not on them to be forced to consider your speech.

Comment: @Marine1 and if you force users to talk to each other, do you really have a community? The purpose of the community is to have choices, no? Surely if a discussion wasn't wanted then meta wouldn't exist. Yet, here you are being able to discuss the actions of an individual. The original premise of this question was based on the fact that you thought it was a moderator that closed your question, if it was, then sure you could ask why and you'd probably get an answer, but this is a regular user who has the choice to answer (not that a moderator doesn't have choice).

Comment: @Script47, The least that is necessary for a community giving power to some do not turn to autocracy is to ensure that those who hold power are held accountable. Which the user granted the rights to close has failed to show.

Comment: @Marine1 Of course they are held accountable, how are they not? Their name is written all over, people have looked over this, and everyone has agreed that they acted correctly. How is that not accountable? Because you were proven wrong? There is a system in place to examine reopen requests, you tried to circumvent it, but that doesn't mean it does not exist. That the outcome is not the one you wish for doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier In this case it is considered desirable that the users can not appeal to the one who makes a decision and refuses to answer them

Comment: Based on the statistics of this question (65 views, -15 votes), I think the community has decided that the individual that closed your question was in-fact, correct in their action.

Comment: @Marine1 rather, when you edit a closed question, it pushes the question in to a queue which is then voted on impartially by different users. Isn't that be fairer and better?

Comment: @Marine1 `"can not appeal"` What in heavens are you even talking about? You asked this question here, you talked about it in chat, roughly 70 people were implied in the process, and you say that you were not given your chance? Can you cite me **any** other online community where you would have had as much support?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Lol, you cited Stack Overflow when I asked you of any other community than Stack Overflow with that level of support. I think I'm done here.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier **ES**.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Marine1 it is SO but in a different language? What's your point? The rules are the same I presume.

Comment: @Script47, It may be cultural but the difference is seizable

Comment: I can't see any problem, in principle, with a structured 'Appeals Procedure', as seemingly desired by some.  A number of acknowledged gold-badge experts, three say, could consider the closure and issue a judgement. In practice, I can't see there being much demand.  It would be very expensive indeed - the panel of experts would make their usual professional charges, and SO would want to cover their costs in adminstering it all.  I mean, if @Marine1 wants to put $5000 up-front to ensure that the costs are covered, then I guess it could be done.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Unfortunately, our sister SO sites in foreign languages might not have similar quality standards. Can't speak for SO.es, but in SO.pt I have seen seemingly well received questions (by their upvotes), even answered by site moderators, which would have been closed here.

Comment: es.stackoverflow.com might be different because it is much smaller that Stack Overflow. Gold users might be contacted less often by users who want to discuss and might be more patient.